# Using grep regex to select to first hyphen

Tags: regex, linux, grep

```
echo "Linux/DEB/mainbinary-0.1.20190424165331-0-armdef.deb" | grep -oE "([^\/]+$)"
```

This prints just the filename, without the directory structure, but I cannot manage to print just mainbinary from that string.  Suggestions?

Comment: Pass to another `grep` maybe?

Comment: I tried that, but I could not get grep to return "up to first hyphen" for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And a `sed` alternative to PS.'s great `grep -oP`

```
echo "Linux/DEB/mainbinary-0.1.20190424165331-0-armdef.deb"  |sed -r 's#^.*/([^-]+).*#\1#'
mainbinary
```

Comment: That 'sed' functionality is supported on all of the hardware my script will potentially work on so you are the winner.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Linux/DEB/mainbinary-0.1.20190424165331-0-armdef.deb"  |grep -oP '.*/\K[^-]+'
mainbinary
```

This will scan till last `/` and ignore everything to its left and keep moving until `-` (excluding)

Comment: The superior power of perl regex :)

Comment: Unfortunately, grep has E/Extended but not P/Perl support on the hardware I am trying to run on.  I do appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: @user2725742 so GNU sed (as required for your accepted answer) is present on every platform you have but GNU grep isn't? You might want to double check that just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX machine:

```
$ echo "Linux/DEB/mainbinary-0.1.20190424165331-0-armdef.deb" | awk -F'[/-]' '{print $3}'
mainbinary
```

Comment: Works well for that example, but unfortunately the directory tree that each .deb lives in is different so indexing does not work.

Comment: That's why you should never just provide 1 sample in your question - always provide enough of a [mcve] to adequately demonstrate your requirements.